# nested repeater show data that matches parent repeater

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater

I am using a repeater to build a custom table. However, I can't figure out how to make the table show subtotal if the next rows tour does not match the previous rows.

Something similar to that.

```
row1 tour1
row2 tour 1
tour1 subtotal
row3 tour2
row4 tour2
subtotal
total

<asp:Repeater ID="ParentRepeater" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>TOUR</th>
                <th>THEME</th>
                <th>ROUTE</th>
                <th>DEPT</th>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%#Container.DataItem("tour")%></td>
            <td align="center"><%#Container.DataItem("theme")%></td>
            <td align="right"><%#Container.DataItem("route")%></td>
            <td align="right"><%#Container.DataItem("dep7")%></td>
            <asp:Repeater ID="ChildRepeater" runat="server"
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table border="1">
                        <tr>
                            <th>BOOKNO</th>
                            <th>PARTY</th>
                            <th>TOUR</th>
                            <th>THEME</th>
                            <th>ROUTE</th>
                            <th>DEPT</th>
                            <th>HOME</th>
                            <th>USERID</th>
                        </tr>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center"><%#Container.DataItem("bookno") %></td>
                        <td><%#Container.DataItem("party")%></td>
                        <td><%#Container.DataItem("tour")%></td>
                        <td align="center"><%#Container.DataItem("theme")%></td>
                        <td align="right"><%#Container.DataItem("route")%></td>
                        <td align="right"><%#Container.DataItem("dep7")%></td>
                        <td align="right"><%#Container.DataItem("home")%></td>
                        <td align="right"><%#Container.DataItem("userid")%></td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </table>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

code behind

```
Protected Sub ItemBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As RepeaterItemEventArgs)
        If args.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Then
            Dim childRepeater As Repeater = DirectCast(args.Item.FindControl("ChildRepeater"), Repeater)
            childRepeater.DataSource = SqlDataSource2
            childRepeater.DataBind()
        End If
    End Sub
```

but this shows all the data in the nested repeater not the ones that match the parentrepeater fields
for example tour,theme,dep7 should match in the child repeater

Comment: you could use two nested repeaters, like in this article: [A quick guide to using nested repeaters in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/AspNetNestedRepeaters.aspx)

Comment: hmm that seems like it could work, i was trying to just write a simple if statement, that checked if the e.row was <> to the e.row.index - 1  column then it would do a subtotal is that completly off

Comment: you would have to generate the HTML for the row containing the subtotals dynamically, right? I guess that may work too, although I think the automatic HTML generation is messier than the nested repeater (which at least keeps all the HTML together in the page).

Comment: i am going to post what i did but i need some help can you take a look

Answer (score 0):

First, add 2 class fields:

```
private int _subTotal; // Not sure what you're summing but you
                       // wrote subtotal in your pseudo-output
private int _lastTourId;
```

Reset these field before you databind your repeater:

```
_subTotal = 0;
_lastTourId = -1;
TourRepeater.DataBind();
```

The create a single level Repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="TourRepeater" ...>
  <HeaderTemplate>...<>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
      Some columns with your tour data
    </tr>
    <PlaceHolder ID="SubTotalRow" ... />
  </ItemTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
    <PlaceHolder ID="SubTotalRow" ... />
  </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Bind this Repeater directly to your tour data, then do this in your OnItemDataBound event handler (I'll have to go for c#):

```
void RepeaterItemDataBound(object source, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
  if (
    e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
    e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem // think you forgot this
  )
  {
    var tour = e.Item.DataItem as Tour;
    if (tour != null)
    {
      if (_lastTourId == -1) { _lastTourId == tour.TourId; } // To avoid subtotal row before first tour
      if (tour.TourId != _lastTourId) // This is a new tour so insert a subtotal row for the previous tour
      {
        var subTotalRow = e.Item.FindControl("SubTotalRow") as PlaceHolder;
        if (subTotalRow != null)
        {
          RenderSummaryRow(subTotalRow, _subTotal);
        }
        _subTotal = tour.SomeValueYouWantToAddToSubTotal;
      }
      else
      {
        _subTotal += tour.SomValueYouWantToAddToSubTotal;
      }
      _lastTourId = tour.TourId;
    }
  }
  else if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer)
  {
    var subTotalRow = e.Item.FindControl("SummaryRow") as PlaceHolder;
    if (summaryTotalRow != null)
    {
      RenderSummaryRow(subTotalRow, _subTotal);
    }
  }
}

private void RenderSummaryRow(PlaceHolder placeHolder, int subTotal)
{
          // create subtotal row manually by either creating TableRow + TableCells and adding them to a placeholder, or
          // just add a literal and create your markup manually as innerHtml. Put your _subtotal value in where you want
}
```

An alternative method is to retrieve your tour data into a DataTable, and retrieve the data WITH ROLLUP etc which will create summary rows automagically. There's several tutorials about this around the web, but I couldn't find the great one I used before I switched to MVC.

Comment: hmmm i converted it to vb.net and got an error here 
       Dim Tour = TryCast(e.Item.DataItem, Tour)
tour is not defined

Comment: Sorry. e.Item.DataItem is null in Footer. See revised code which also fixes a bug in subtotal calculation.

Comment: yeah bt the error is at the    
   Dim tour = TryCast(e.Item.DataItem, Tour)

Comment: var tour = e.Item.DataItem as Tour;

Comment: You're using a DataTable as the datasource? Try `Dim dataRow = TryCast(e.Item.DataItem, DataRow)`. Replace all references to tour with dataRow.

Comment: i dont know this isnt working for me, i just want to have a list of all similar tours listed one after another then a subtotal, then another tour, list those tours with a subtotal. im not even that worried about a grand total at this point

Comment: and my datasource is just sqldatasource1